# How can I log out of Steam remotely?

Tags: steam

I was playing TF2 at a friend's house and I believe I forgot to log off. Does deauthorizing all computers with Steam Guard log me out, too? Or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Pretty sure you can only be 'logged in' to one computer at a time

Comment: @BenCraig that used to be the case, but not anymore.

Comment: Just tested: De-authorising all computers will not log off any computers already logged in, though if it's logged out it will need to be re-authorised. Can't you just ask your friend to log you out?

Comment: You must trust a friend to do it for you.

Comment: Maybe changing your password will force your account to log off?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can now log out on all other computers by clicking the "Deauthorize all other devices" button at https://store.steampowered.com/twofactor/manage.

Comment: I'm a little shocked that this worked from my phone while I was at the gym

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to "deauthorizing all other devices" is to simply launch a game you purchased through Steam. It should show a window stating that you're logged in on another device, and you'll be able to choose whether or not to log out of said remote device.

Answer (score -4):

All you need to do is log on from another location. All other steam sessions will be automatically logged off.

If you saved your credentials on this other computer, then that is another story. I would de-authorize that other PC and also change my password.

[Here is the reference for Steam not allowing multiple log-in sessions.](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8963-EIKC-3767#simultaneous)

Comment: Slight discrepancy: you **can** be logged into multiple computers at the same time (otherwise, in-home streaming would never work), but you *cannot* play two games on two computers with the same account simultaneously (which is what the link you posted explains).

Comment: Good point. I think you can only be logged on from two computers at once if you are on the same network. Can't find information on that though.

Comment: @JMD Nope - It's as many computers, anywhere... But only one can be playing at any one time.